# Awesome wm setting size for the tasklist item

Tags: lua, widget, desktop, window-managers, awesome-wm

I'm coding a custom vertical wibox that contains my tasklist, I want it to look like this: 
[image]

but instead of being fixed height, the tasklist items just take up all the available space. Here's the result: 
[image]

Here's my code so far:

```
function render_task_box(s)
    myotherbox[s] = awful.wibox({ position = "left", screen = s, ontop =
    true, width = 200 })

    mytasklist[s] = awful.widget.tasklist(
        s,
        awful.widget.tasklist.filter.currenttags,
        mytasklist.buttons,
        nil,
        nil,
        wibox.layout.flex.vertical())




    local middle_layout = wibox.layout.fixed.vertical()
    middle_layout:add(mytasklist[s])

    local layout = wibox.layout.align.vertical()
    layout:set_middle(middle_layout)

    myotherbox[s]:set_widget(layout)

end
```

So how do I get wanted result? (or at least set height of tasklist icon)

**Update**

Looked up some [docs](https://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/wibox.layout.flex.html) and tried this:

```
local l = wibox.layout.flex.vertical();
l:set_max_widget_size(20)
```

It did nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading some of the awesome's source code I've found a solution.

Somewhere in your script require this

```
local common = require("awful.widget.common")
```

Then create a function that overrides task update function:

```
function list_update(w, buttons, label, data, objects)
    -- call default widget drawing function
    common.list_update(w, buttons, label, data, objects)
    -- set widget size
    w:set_max_widget_size(20)
end
```

Then pass this function to tasklist

```
    mytasklist[s] = awful.widget.tasklist(s,
    awful.widget.tasklist.filter.currenttags,
    mytasklist.buttons,
    nil,
    list_update,
    wibox.layout.flex.vertical())
```

Thats it!

Comment: @Linas you can check out my awesome config here https://github.com/ThePinkPanther/MinimalAwesome it has this solution implemented and much more.