# awesomewm - size of tasklist icons

Tags: lua, resize, window-managers, awesome-wm

how to change the icon size of the tasklist?
I am working with a non-modified, just installed awesome wm build and cant seem to figure this one out.

I tried

```
s.mytasklist = awful.widget.tasklist {
        screen  = s,
        filter  = awful.widget.tasklist.filter.currenttags,
        buttons = tasklist_buttons,
        style = {
                icon_size = 10,
```

from https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/widgets/awful.widget.tasklist.html

and this [Awesome wm setting size for the tasklist item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293571/awesome-wm-setting-size-for-the-tasklist-item)

both solutions wont work.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In AwesomeWM <= 4.2, you cannot. In 4.3 and newer, you need to provide a `widget_template`. The 2 main way to lock the size are [the constraint container](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/widget_containers/wibox.container.constraint.html) or the [forced height](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/widgets/awful.widget.clienticon.html#wibox.widget.base.forced_height) property.